# spring security open ldap memberOf

Tags: spring, spring-security, openldap

I am trying to configure open ldap authentication using spring security 3.1
it seems I can authenticate just fine, but the roles are not coming through, redirecting me to access-denied-page

using command line utility ldapsearch, I have to specify "memberOf" parameter, otherwise none of the roles get printed out.

Do I need to set a special parameter for ldap-authentication-provider?

```
 <s:ldap-server url="ldaps://IP:636/dc=blank,dc=loc"
        manager-dn="cn=blank,ou=blank,ou=blank,ou=blank,dc=blank,dc=loc"
        manager-password="password"  />
 <s:authentication-manager>
     <s:ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-filter="uid={0}"
            user-search-base=""
            group-search-base=""
            group-search-filter=""
            group-role-attribute="memberOf"
     />
  </s:authentication-manager>
```